# Is there a less verbose way to unwrap maybe values in Elm

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I've been running into a frequent issue in elm where I have a function that depends on multiple maybe values being Just. Is there a less verbose way to write this code:

```
commandIf apples bananas oranges =
        case apples of
            Just apples_ ->
                case bananas of
                    Just bananas_ ->
                        case oranges of
                            Just oranges_ ->
                                someCommand apples_ bananas_ oranges_

                            Nothing ->
                                Cmd.none

                    Nothing ->
                        Cmd.none

            Nothing ->
                Cmd.none
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need all three values at the same time you can match them together as a tuple and leave all other combinations (when one of them or several are `Nothing`) to the fallback case:

```
commandIf apples bananas oranges =
  case (apples, bananas, oranges) of
    (Just apples_, Just bananas_, Just oranges_) ->
        someCommand apples_ bananas_ oranges_

    _ ->
        Cmd.none
```

Comment: Oh that's awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @tanman actually I know very little about Elm, probably there are other ways. It's just very similar to Haskell in which I have significantly more knowledge. In Haskell there are at least 3 more ways to write it: _do-notation_ and _list-comprehension_. But I don't think these constructions exist in Elm ([nope](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/621)).

Comment: @laughedelic: I know nothing about Haskell, but have provided some Elm alternatives in answer below :)

Answer (score 11):

@laughedelic's answer is very good. Just wanted to offer some alternative and more generic solutions too, since verbose `Maybe` unwrapping is an issue I also ran into when I started out in Elm.

If you have a **fixed number of `Maybe` values**, you can use `map2, map3` etc to do what you want ([docs here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.0.0/Maybe#map3)):

```
commandIf apples bananas oranges =
  Maybe.map3 someCommand apples bananas oranges
  |> Maybe.withDefault Cmd.none
```

Here, `someCommand` is your functions that takes 3 arguments, and returns a some command.

`Maybe.map3` applies this function only if all 3 variables are `Just x`, and wraps it in one `Maybe` type. So the result is `Just (someCommand apples bananas oranges)` if all 3 have a value. Otherwise, the function returns `Nothing`.

This result is then "piped" into `Maybe.withDefault`. Which returns a `Cmd.none` if the input is `Nothing`, and otherwise returns the value (your command), without the `Just`.

If you would have **a list of `Maybe` values** of unknown length, you could do something this:

```
keepOnlyJusts : List (Maybe a) -> List a
keepOnlyJusts listOfMaybes =
  listOfMaybes
  |> List.filterMap identity

newList = keepOnlyJusts [ Just 1, Nothing, Just 3 ]   -- == [1,3]
```

where the result is a list (could be empty) where only the values are kept.

Comment: This should be the top-voted answer. `Maybe.map3` is the most idiomatic way of processing multiple maybe values instead of case matching a tuple of Just values.

Comment: An absolute must-read article that goes through these in detail: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/maybe-mechanics

Answer (score 1):

`Maybe.map3` solves your particular case, but this answer is about the general pattern of *chaining* maybe values using `Maybe.andThen`.

```
commandIf a_ b_ c_ =
  a_ |> Maybe.andThen (\a ->
    b_ |> Maybe.andThen (\b ->
      c_ |> Maybe.andThen (Just << someCommand a b)))
  |> Maybe.withDefault Cmd.none
```

Comment: This answer basically duplicates the code from the @wintvelt's answer.

Comment: No (that's my other answer--now deleted). This one introduces `Maybe.andThen`.

Comment: OK. Although I still think it's not much less verbose.